# React Native: Z Index on selection

Tags: react-native, z-index

There have been a lot of posts regarding z index and layer ordering but none with much of a solution. Its easy enough to layer things as you need, but if you need dynamic layer re-ordering it becomes a problem. Like for example I have four moveable elements, when one is selected it should move above the others but they are already in set order so each moves under the other.

If they are layered in render order than how can the active item move to the front and move above the other three?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may solve this by changing the rendering order of your components. Lets say you have some items you want to render in an array and an index of the selected item, so your render method may look like this:

```
render() {
  const items = ....;
  const selectedIndex = ...;
  return (
    <View>
      {items.filter((item, index) => index != selectedIndex)}
      {items[selectedIndex]}
    </View>
  );  
}
```

This way your selected item would always render last and be on top of the others.

Comment: Thanks, that's absolutely perfect.

Comment: Could you offer an example of what such an `items` array might look like?